# How to calculate cos, sin, and tan in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, trigonometry

How do you calculate trig functions like cos, sin, tan in the iOS SDK?

I tried `tan(45)` but it returns wrong output. Any help?

Comment: A little bit off-topic, but you might want to look up "Taylor Series".  It is a method that allows you to approximate sin and cos to arbitrary precision.

Comment: @Rising Star: unless you use a lot of care in the implementation, Taylor series will not be nearly as accurate as calling the math library.

Answer (score 6):

Most math libraries use [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radians), not degrees.

Answer (score 3):

functions like cos, sin and tan are in the standard library and can be used by including math.h. You can get a good overview of these by typing '`man math`' in a Terminal window on your Mac. More specific info can be read by typing '`man sin`' for example. You will then see that sin() takes a radians arguments, not degrees. Search here on Stack Overflow if you don't know how to convert radians to degrees.

Comment: Bingo.  `man sin`: "The sin() function computes the sine of x (measured in radians)."

Answer (score 0):

If you get the output in Radians you can convert it to degrees.

Radian * (180/pi)

pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433.......